# How to pipe the output of a command to `/dev/null` in python

Tags: python, bash, stderr

I am trying to pipe the output of the following command to `/dev/null` so that it doesn't get printed for the user that is running the program.

```
import os
os.system("ping -c 1 192.168.unknown.host > /dev/null")
```

But I get the error:

```
ping: unknown host  192.168.unknown.host
```

The problem is that this message is produced by something other than `stdout`, probably `stderr` and I can easily redirect it to `/dev/null` using

```
ping -c 1 192.168.unknown.host >& /dev/null
```

However, when I use that in python, I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number
```

Is it possible to solve this? (I just don't want that message to be printed).

Comment: `&>` instead of `>&`. Or is this just a typo? This works only with bash 4, IIRC. Otherwise use `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: It's not a type, that command works in shell but not in python (either case); But your suggestion worked well.

Comment: `os.system` is using `/bin/sh` which does not support the `>&` redirection. Try `/bin/sh -c '<your command>'` from the shell and it'll fail too.

Comment: It works in terminal, but python returns that strange error.

Answer (score 10):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(
    ['ping', "-c", "192.168.unknown.host"],
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
)
```

As pointed out by Ashwini Chaudhary, for Python below 3.3 you have to manually open `os.devnull`:

```
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
    subprocess.Popen(
        ['ping', "-c", "192.168.unknown.host"],
        stdout=DEVNULL,
        stderr=DEVNULL,
    )
```

Comment: Note that `subprocess.DEVNULL` is only for Python 3.3+, for earlier versions you'll have to use object returned by `open(os.devnull)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. It offers several methods that can handle standard input, output and error.

Something like this:

```
import subprocess as sub
import shlex

cmd = "ping -c 1 myhost"
cmdarg = shlex.split(cmd)
p = sub.Popen(cmdarg,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
```